# ExtJs : Container must not receive child item's click events and Process only events on container

Tags: extjs, extjs7

I want to process mouse up/down events in the empty area(marked in color) which belongs to container.
As shown in the picture, container has menu bar to the left and window standard buttons to the right. Expected behavior is : click on menu items/buttons must trigger their event handlers and click on empty area(marked in color) must be processed by container to support window drag.

I tried this in container:

```
listeners: {
    mousedown: {
        fn: function() {
            _mousepressed = true;
        },
        element: 'el'
    },
    mouseup: {
        fn: function() {
            _mousepressed = false;
        },
        element: 'el'
    },
```

When clicked on menu item button, the event is first coming to container's mouseup handler and then button handler is called. Instead , I expect not to receive event in container when child items are clicked. I need clicks on empty areas in container.

Is there any extjs way to identify events on parent container and not on its chid items?

[image]

Comment: You can try to add another container (which you marked with yellow) insidde the outer container, and use the mouse listeners on this smaller container only.

Comment: yes, analyzed this approach. I can add One container for toolbar area with flex:1 and other container for dragging. But, I'm looking for more direct approach. I wanted to know why the events come to container first. According to event bubbling, first the button should receive the event and then it should bubble up to container, right? Here, container is receiving the mouseup event first.